# Joining Arrays to insert in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a small application that will record data of share-holders of our company and the shares held by them and transfer record etc. I have a table named `stocks_inventory` with columns `id`,  `randnum` and `certnum`.
While the `id` is autoincrement in mysql, I have two PHP functions to define `randnum` and `certnum`.  The purpose of `randnum`  is to have a kind of code on physically printed certificate for verification purpose to safeguard against faking / forgery.  This is an additional feature to physical signature of our directors.
I have two functions named `createRAC()` and `certificate_numbers()` to create two simple arrays.  I want to join these arrays as Key=>value pairs and insert into a MySQL table.

I have already written and tested the two functions provided below:

```
<?php
// RAC = Random Authentication Code
function createRAC() {
    echo $rac = hash('md5', (rand(111111,999999)));
}
$i = 0;
$num = 1000;
$array = array();
while ($i++ < $num) {
    $array[] = createRAC();
}
?>

<?php
function certificate_numbers($start, $count, $digits) {
   $result = array();
   for ($n = $start; $n < $start + $count; $n++) {
       $result[] = str_pad($n, $digits, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
   return $result;
}
$numbers = certificate_numbers(1, 1000, 4);
print_r($numbers);
?>
```

I need help with PDO statement for joining these arrays and a MySQL query to insert 1000 key=>value pairs at one time. And I want to be able to repeat this function as the number of shares/shareholders grows.

Comment: `createRAC()` needs to return the value and not `echo` it.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use something like this

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO stocks_inventory(randnum,certnum) VALUES ';
foreach($array as $key => &$randnum) 
  $query.= ($key ? ',' : '') . "($randnum," . $numbers[$key] . ")";
```